# Whats Wrong with this javascript Function Checklis using OnClick to hide <tr> table and div

Tags: javascript

My code isn't running well

**Javascript**

```
function CheckNik() {
  var tfnik = 'input[name="nik"]';
  var tfnonik = 'input[name="nonik"]';
  var nnik = tfnik;
  var nonik = tfnonik;
  var nn = $(nonik).is(':checked');
    if(nn) {
      $(nnik).val('0000000000000000');
      document.getElementById('divnik').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('divdomisili').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      $(nnik).val('');
      document.getElementById('divnik').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('divdomisili').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
            <tr>
              <td>NIK<span class="red">*</span></td>
              <td colspan="2">
                <div id="divnik" style="display:block">
                  <input type="text" name="nik" class="" style="" maxlength="16" id="nik">
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -5px; display: block;" id="ceknik"> 
                  <input type="checkbox" name="nonik" id="nonik" onclick="javascript:CheckNik();">Tidak memiliki NIK
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <div id="divdomisili" style="display:block">
            <tr>
              <td>Domisili<span class="red">*</span></td>
                <td>

                  <select name="propinsi_mustahik" id="propinsi" style="width: 80px;" class="combo-box" onchange="get_cities(this.value);" >
                    <option value="">- Propinsi -</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name="kabupaten" id="kabupaten" class="select" style="width: 80px;" onchange="get_districts(this.value);" >
                  <option value="">- Kab -</option>
                  </select>
                  <input type="hidden" id="keca" name="keca">
                  <select name="kecamatan" id="kecamatan" class="select" style="width: 80px;" onchange="getListOfVillages(this.value);">
                  <option value="">- Kec -</option> 
                  </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </div>
</table>
```

**This is my demo code :** https://jsfiddle.net/kpLccfL4/

I don't know why when I check the checkbox(with OnClick function), can't hide  table and DIV together, just the DIV hides..

**I want to hide both `id="divnik"` and `id="divdomisili"`. but this code just hide "divnik**

Comment: can you be a little clear. I dont understood what you actually wanna want?

Comment: I want to hide id="divnik" and id="divdomisili" but this code just hide "divnik"

Comment: You cant wrap a TR inside a div as you did.

Comment: ooh .. i can't do it ya?

Comment: <tr  id="divdomisili">
you can do this instead.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kpLccfL4/3/

Comment: but not neat when i'm ceklis then unceklis .. not nice

Comment: another suggestion ? @Feeda

Comment: this is just because, a div cannot be placed inside a `<table></table>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Your second code block would be invalid html.  elements can only appear inside a  element. They can also be children of , , and  but those elements would need to be children of the table element. So ultimately, a tr needs a table ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

This div **divdomisili** `is not getting rendered properly on the page`.

this is because of the mismatch in formatting!

`you cannot embed a div inside <table></table> element directly.`

**you would try this instead of your html:**

```js
function CheckNik() {
  var tfnik = 'input[name="nik"]';
  var tfnonik = 'input[name="nonik"]';
  var nnik = tfnik;
  var nonik = tfnonik;
  var nn = $(nonik).is(':checked');
  if (nn) {
    $(nnik).val('0000000000000000');
    document.getElementById('divnik').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('divdomisili').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    $(nnik).val('');
    document.getElementById('divnik').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('divdomisili').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Including JQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Html Code Here -->

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>NIK<span class="red">*</span>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div id="divnik" style="display:block">
        <input type="text" name="nik" class="" style="" maxlength="16" id="nik">
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -5px; display: block;" id="ceknik">
        <input type="checkbox" name="nonik" id="nonik" onclick="javascript:CheckNik();">Tidak memiliki NIK
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table><!-- Closed the table [The Malfunctioning Div] -->
<div id="divdomisili" style="display:block">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Domisili<span class="red">*</span>
      </td>
      <td>

        <select name="propinsi_mustahik" id="propinsi" style="width: 80px;" class="combo-box" onchange="get_cities(this.value);">
          <option value="">- Propinsi -</option>
        </select>
        <select name="kabupaten" id="kabupaten" class="select" style="width: 80px;" onchange="get_districts(this.value);">
          <option value="">- Kab -</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" id="keca" name="keca">
        <select name="kecamatan" id="kecamatan" class="select" style="width: 80px;" onchange="getListOfVillages(this.value);">
          <option value="">- Kec -</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <table>
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: since i don't know the language that you have used, i am not aware of the content you have placed. based on them, html must be edited to get the page look how it should.

Comment: another way is that you can embed the whole div inside a `<table><tr><td>`<div></div>`</td></tr><table>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
        <tr>
          <td>NIK<span class="red">*</span></td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <div id="divnik" style="display:block">
              <input type="text" name="nik" class="" style="" maxlength="16" id="nik">
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -5px; display: block;" id="ceknik"> 
              <input type="checkbox" name="nonik" id="nonik" onclick="javascript:CheckNik();">Tidak memiliki NIK
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="divdomisili" style="display:block">
          <td>Domisili<span class="red">*</span></td>
            <td>

              <select name="propinsi_mustahik" id="propinsi" style="width: 80px;" class="combo-box" onchange="get_cities(this.value);" >
                <option value="">- Propinsi -</option>
              </select>
              <select name="kabupaten" id="kabupaten" class="select" style="width: 80px;" onchange="get_districts(this.value);" >
              <option value="">- Kab -</option>
              </select>
              <input type="hidden" id="keca" name="keca">
              <select name="kecamatan" id="kecamatan" class="select" style="width: 80px;" onchange="getListOfVillages(this.value);">
              <option value="">- Kec -</option> 
              </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

You can't use `div` inside `table`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in second div block. Your second div must be inside  tr td but tr td is in div while your first div inside tr td so your second div should be inside tr td

Here is your second div block which is inside tr td.

```
<tr>
  <td>Domisili<span class="red">*</span></td>
    <td>
     <div id="divdomisili" style="display:block">
      <select name="propinsi_mustahik" id="propinsi" style="width: 80px;" class="combo-box" onchange="get_cities(this.value);" >
        <option value="">- Propinsi -</option>
      </select>
      <select name="kabupaten" id="kabupaten" class="select" style="width: 80px;" onchange="get_districts(this.value);" >
      <option value="">- Kab -</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" id="keca" name="keca">
      <select name="kecamatan" id="kecamatan" class="select" style="width: 80px;" onchange="getListOfVillages(this.value);">
      <option value="">- Kec -</option> 
      </select>
      </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems problem in the js code. You can not select html element with code javascript and then apply jQuery method. Also use id in `tr` element instead of `div`.

Try this code

HTML

```
<tr id="divdomisili">
    <td>Domisili<span class="red">*</span></td>
    <td>
        <select name="propinsi_mustahik" id="propinsi" style="width: 80px;" class="combo-box" onchange="get_cities(this.value);" >
            <option value="">- Propinsi -</option>
        </select>
        <select name="kabupaten" id="kabupaten" class="select" style="width: 80px;" onchange="get_districts(this.value);" >
            <option value="">- Kab -</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" id="keca" name="keca">
            <select name="kecamatan" id="kecamatan" class="select" style="width: 80px;"id="divdomisili" onchange="getListOfVillages(this.value);">
                  <option value="">- Kec -</option> 
            </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
function CheckNik() {
      var tfnik = 'input[name="nik"]';
      var tfnonik = 'input[name="nonik"]';
      var nnik = tfnik;
      var nonik = tfnonik;
      var nn = document.getElementById("nonik").checked;

      if(nn) {
          nnik.value = '0000000000000000';
          document.getElementById('divnik').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('divdomisili').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          nnik.value = '';
          document.getElementById('divnik').s`enter code here`tyle.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById('divdomisili').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
```